# Org-agenda: how to show todo's with scheduled date within a time interval?

Tags: org-mode

I want to use org-agenda to show todo's with scheduled date or deadline date within at certain time interval. For instance, I want to show todo's with deadline between today and one week ahead (today +7d). I have tried to do this by the following code:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
   ("d" "daily "(
     (tags-todo "+DEADLINE>=\"<today>\" +DEADLINE<=\"<today + 7d>\" (
        (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-down))
        ))
  ))))
```

But the code does not give what I want, instead my agenda show all todo's with deadline in the future, not only those with deadline between today and one week forward. How can I make org-agenda only show todo's for a certain time interval? Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: I suggest you have a look at column-view to see if one of the settings will give you the information you seek:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-view.html#Column-view  It is basically an overlay grid with additional details that can be customized -- it is displayed on top of the `*Org-Agenda*` buffer without modifying what's underneath.  I've only played a bit with that option, so I'm not sure as to its full potential.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the column-view will answer my question. I use column-view when I want to see explicitly property data for todo

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question -- I thought you were seeking a certain visual appearance of a search result.  Based on your comment and after reading the question again, it appears you are seeking a particular search result without the need for any special/different visual appearance.  I apologize for the erroneous comment above.  You may try using `org-agenda-list` instead of `org-tags-view` -- the former is specifically designed for a span of time from 1 day to infinity depending upon the need.

Comment: Thanks :)  you are right, I seek a particular filter result. Now I see all my todo's in the future, but I do not want to see all of them, just the ones for the next n days.

Comment: When using `org-agenda-list` instead of `org-tags-view`, variables such as `org-agenda-start-day` and `org-agenda-span` can control the time frame for which deadlines or scheduled tasks are displayed.  A regexp restriction can be added to the search criteria to focus in on certain tags.  I haven't played around with `org-agenda-filter-by-tag`, but that also looks interesting.  http://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html  Here is the link to the regexp skip/include stuff:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html

Comment: I do not understand your answer (I am a emacs newbie). Does your answer suggest how I can change my code above, using org-agenda-custom-commans, or do I have to make a totally different code?

Comment: When you use things like `tags-todo` in the `org-agenda-custom-commands`, you are telling Emacs to use `org-tags-view`, which is a different searching function than `org-agenda-list`.  The latter is specifically for spans of time and deadlines/scheduled tasks.  The shorthand form for `org-agenda-list` when using `org-agenda-custom-commands` is `agenda`.  Here is a link to a few different exaples from someone's .emacs file:  https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/org-custom-agenda-views.el  You can probably also use `org-tags-view` with the right criteria, but I haven't done it.

Comment: Using an `agenda` query instead of a `tags-todo` query will force the results to be sorted by date, which this is asking for them to be sorted by todo state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that `<today + 7d>` is a valid time specification — you meant to say `<+7d>`.  Additionally, there's no need to use an embedded list for just one condition.  Finally, you're missing a pair of parantheses around the settings.

The following should do what you want:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("d" "daily"
     tags-todo "DEADLINE>=\"<today>\"&DEADLINE<=\"<+7d>\""
     ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-down))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. None of my todo's with deadline within the next 7 d show up when using your code.

Comment: Yes, your code works. It did work when I added the extra pair of parentheses. Why are they needed?

Comment: My fault, I did not add the parentheses you mentioned :) Now it works! Thanks. Why are the extra pair of parentheses needed?

Comment: Settings have the same syntax as a `let` binding: `((opt1 val1) (opt2 val2)...)`.  See the docstring for `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

Comment: My original code was for block agenda. That is maybe the reason for lacking pair of parenthses. How can your code be changed to a block agenda, for instance having one line for today + 7d and another line for +7d to +14d?

Comment: I mixed things up here :) ..now it works also in agenda block mode. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, is there a way to set my timeinterval to end at a certain day within the week of "today". For instance, from today to sunday this week?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.