# How to subset org headlines by timestamp and tag

Tags: org-mode

I have just started using emacs-org to index news headlines.

I've adopted the convention: `<2018-10-10 Wed> Key Headline :TAG:`

Here's a concrete example (with made up headlines).  Say that i'm tracking news about Trump. A collection of headlines may look at below -- i use `C-c C-d` to insert the timestamp generated by `org-deadline-string`.

```
* Trump says China not seeking deal seriously :China:
 DEADLINE: <2018-10-11 Thu> 
* Trump says he will meet Kim :NorthKorea:
 DEADLINE: <2018-10-10 Wed> 
** Trump says NK is special place
** Trump says Kim a good man
* Trump says China ready to do a trade deal :China:
 DEADLINE: <2018-10-08 Mon> 
* Trump says not happy with Kim :NorthKorea:
 DEADLINE: <2018-09-02 Sun>
```

I wish to query these headlines by tag and timestamp.  Say to see only headlines tagged `:China:` after 10 October.

How might i do this?

Comment: I think some more details are needed. What do you mean by "subset"? Do you mean query? Sort?

Comment: The `org-deadline-string` and `org-scheduled-string` can be customized to say anything; e.g., instead of `DEADLINE:` it could say `DATE:`.  Org-mode has built-in sorting options for deadline and scheduled entries.  To insert the timestamps, use `C-c C-d` or `C-c C-s`.  Org-mode expects one or more leading stars at the beginning of a headline.

Comment: @user1462309 i added some more detail.

Comment: @lawlist i found that `C-c <` gave me what i wanted with dates, as i don't really want any text.  Is it possible to get by using these types of entries? If so, how do i next select entries in some date range?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the format you wish to use does not match the `org-complex-heading-regexp`; and, much of the builtin sorting and org-agenda stuff may not work as one would expect.  There is always a way to sort things in Emacs using a proper regex; however, you may need to create some custom stuff to make it all work.  In an `org-mode` buffer you can type `M-x describe-variable RET org-complex-heading-regexp RET` and see what I am talking about.  Then you can grep the org source code directory for `org-complex-heading-regexp` and see just how many functions rely upon that format ....

Comment: @lawlist -- okay i'm happy enough using the `C-c C-s` timestamps ... it doesn't make that much difference to me.  I'm new to emacs, so simplicity is a higher priority.  So assuming `C-c C-s` timestamps, how do i now see all headlines matching some tag, in some date-range?

Comment: If we take your example and paste it into a `*scratch*` buffer and enable `org-mode` by calling `M-x org-mode` and then pull up a helpful regex mode by typing `M-x re-builder` and we paste the `org-complex-heading-regexp` into the `*Re-Builder*` buffer -- `"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)??\\(?:[  ]+\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)\\)?[  ]*$"`, we see that your proposed timestamps are treated as part of the *title/true-headline*.  That does not mean you can't do it your way; it just means that some of the sorting stuff that is built-in may not work.

Comment: In general, questions in this venue should be phrased in such a manner so that only a few answers will be something that just about everyone can agree upon as being correct.  The question, as is, should probably be tightened up so that it does not seek opinions.  E.g., "How to programmatically sort headings (containing timestamps) in `org-mode` by timestamp date/time ascending and also descending?"  [For example, you want to select the region and sort all lines by timestamp up; and, then by timestamp down.]"

Comment: Here is the page from the org manual regarding how to conduct advanced searches:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:   Copy and paste the following test data into a `*scratch*` buffer:

```
* Trump says China not seeking deal seriously :China:
  DEADLINE: <2018-10-11 Thu>
* Trump says he will meet Kim :NorthKorea:
  DEADLINE: <2018-10-10 Wed>
** Trump says NK is special place
** Trump says Kim a good man
* Trump says China ready to do a trade deal :China:
  DEADLINE: <2018-10-08 Mon>
* Trump says not happy with Kim :NorthKorea:
  DEADLINE: <2018-09-02 Sun>
```

Step 2:  Save the buffer to a file, e.g., `~/Desktop/test.org`.  By default, Emacs will assume the new file with an `*.org` extension should be `org-mode`.  We do not have to use that extension, but it is convenient and helpful for a variety of reasons ... beyond the scope of this answer.  If the buffer is not in `org-mode` after saving it, then type `M-x org-mode`.

Step 3:  Add the new file to the variable `org-agenda-files`, which can be done a variety of ways.  [For more details on how to configure that variable, type `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-files RET` or `C-h v` ....]  E.g., `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Desktop/test.org"))`

Step 4:  Type `M-x eval-expression RET (org-tags-view nil "DEADLINE>=\"<2018-10-11>\"&DEADLINE<=\"<+1y>\"&ALLTAGS={china}") RET`.  [The keyboard shortcut to evaluate an expression is `M-:`]  This example is searching for all matching criteria from 10/11/2018 to 10/10/2019 (i.e., 1 year) and tags with a regex of `china`.

Step 5:  The result returned in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer is:

```
Headlines with TAGS match: DEADLINE>="<2018-10-11>"&DEADLINE<="<+1y>"&ALLTAGS={china}

Press ‘C-u r’ to search again with new search string

test:       Trump says China not seeking deal seriously                :China:
```

To create custom preset commands, check out this example:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22062/2287

To learn about advanced searching, check out this page from the org manual:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

The above-example can be used in conjunction with let-bound variables such as `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` .... [Beyond the scope of this answer.]

Instead of using a file-visiting-buffer, the user may wish to use a sparse-tree search [which can be either a non-file-visiting-bufffer or a file-visiting-buffer] ... again, beyond the scope of this answer ...